# Populating Textboxes with Multiple ComboBoxes

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, textbox

I am writing a program that has three tabs.

On the first tab, the user enters information about a customer account, which is then sent to a `combobox` on the second and third tab called `clients`.  On the second tab, the user enters information either about stocks or mutual funds.  The stock information goes to the stock `combobox` on the third tab, and the mutual fund information goes to the mutual fund `combobox` on the third tab.

The problem I am having is that I can only fill in one field of information and be able to populate `textboxes` with the selected item in the `combobox`.  For example, if I enter information about the customer account -- and then choose that option in the `combobox` -- it will populate `textboxes` with with that information.  But, if I were to try and choose an option from the stock or mutual fund `combobox`, then the appropriate `textboxes` will not populate with the information.  I have no idea why a selection from the first `combobox` is the only one that will populate the `textboxes`.

Here's the code for populating the `textboxes`:

```
  private void cboClientsTab3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomerAccount custAccount = account[cboClientsTab3.SelectedIndex] as CustomerAccount;
        if (custAccount != null)
        {
            txtAccountNumberTab3.Text = custAccount.GetAccountNumber();
            txtCustomerNameTab3.Text = custAccount.GetCustomerName();
            txtCustomerAddressTab3.Text = custAccount.GetCustomerAddress();
            txtCustomerPhoneNumberTab3.Text = custAccount.GetCustomerPhoneNo();
        }

    }

    private void cboStocksTab3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stock aStock = account[cboStocksTab3.SelectedIndex] as Stock;
        if (aStock != null)
        {
            txtStockIDTab3.Text = aStock.GetInvestmentID();
            txtStockNameTab3.Text = aStock.GetInvestmentName();
            txtStockSymbolTab3.Text = aStock.GetInvestmentSymbol();
            txtStockSharesTab3.Text = aStock.GetInvestmentShare().ToString();
            txtStockPriceTab3.Text = aStock.GetStockPrice().ToString();
        }

    }

    private void cboMutualFundsTab3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MutualFund aMutualFund = account[cboMutualFundsTab3.SelectedIndex] as MutualFund;
        if (aMutualFund!=null)
        {
            txtMutualIDTab3.Text=aMutualFund.GetInvestmentID();
            txtMutualNameTab3.Text=aMutualFund.GetInvestmentName();
            txtMutualSymbolTab3.Text=aMutualFund.GetInvestmentSymbol();
            txtMutualSharesTab3.Text=aMutualFund.GetInvestmentShare().ToString();
            txtNAVTab3.Text=aMutualFund.GetNAV().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell from the code.  I'd recommend stepping through using the VS debugger, to see where the problem arises.

Comment: It doesn't really tell me anything when i step through it.  I don't understand why will only populate textboxes from the first used combobox.

Comment: So when you put a breakpoint in *cboStocksTab3_SelectedIndexChanged*, and select an item from the combo box, does the breakpoint get hit?  Is *aStock* null?  Are *GetInvestmentID()*, etc returning empty strings/null?  Have to narrow it down.

Comment: I set a breakpoint in cboStocksTab_SelectedIndexChanged and when I made a selection from the combobox it did get hit.  But how to I tell where the issue is?

Comment: Well first, does it get past the **(aStock != null)** condition?  Second, are you familiar with Watches?  I'd add a watch on **aStock** and inspect its values.

Comment: No, when I make a selection from that combobox this line is highlighted. "CustomerAccount custAccount = account[cboClientsTab3.SelectedIndex] as CustomerAccount;"

Comment: Makes sense.  It seems the problem is that the wrong event handler is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Per our chat above, the problem seems to be that **cboStocksTab3** and **cboMutualFundsTab3** are wired up to the wrong event handler (namely **cboClientsTab3_SelectedIndexChanged**).  Check where your *SelectedIndexChanged* event is added to the elements, and change to the correct ones.  That should solve your problem.

Comment: What do you mean check where it is added to the elements.  The three SelectedIndexChanged events are just in the form of my program.  How should they be wired up?

Comment: Well, the event has to be wired up somewhere, probably elsewhere in the form code.  It depends though, I guess: are you using WPF or classic Windows Forms?

Comment: It's a Windows Form Application in VisualStudio 2010

Comment: I still do not understand how I have the SelectedIndexChanged set up incorrect though.

Comment: Ok.  You have to go to the design view of the form.  Click on the combo box, and check for the **Events** tab in your properties window.  Change the **Selected** property from **cboClientsTab3_SelectedIndexChanged** to the correct value (eg, **cboStocksTab3_SelectedIndexChanged**)